# Dynamic Entity problem

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, salesforce

I am using a Dynamic Entity to enter a new Event.

The basic form works correctly, but I want to pre-populate some of the fields based on user selection.

I have done this by setting the field value in the Event object e.g

```
acc.Subject="Test Subject";
```

This works for all fields except lookup fields.

I want to be able to pre fill in the current user as the Assigned To (owner) person, and tried

```
acc.OwnerId="005200054016IZ5AAM";
```

But this leaves the field blank.

Is there any way that I can pre fill in the Assigned To field?

The complete code I am using is:-

```
                    var itemClass : Class = MetadataUtil.getItemClassForType( _selectedEntity );
                    if ( itemClass == DynamicEntity ){
                        var acc:DynamicEntity = new itemClass( _selectedEntity );
                        acc.OwnerId="005200540016IZ5AAM";
                        acc.Subject="Test Subject";                         
                        _createFieldContainer.render(acc); 
                        }
```

When I use this the subject is filled in with Test subject, but the Asigned To box is blank.

Thanks

Roy

Additional Information:-

When I open the Dynamic Entity ther following screen is displayed:-

[image]

I am trying to populate the field Assigned To with the current user's name.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  You use the word 'field' a lot.  Are you referring to TextInput controls?  Or properties in an object?  Or something else?

Comment: I am referring to properties in an object.
What I want to happen is that when the DynamicEntity box opens with the details of the new Event that the Assigned to selection box is filled with the current users name.

Comment: Seems like you're doing some major hacking to do something that seems incredibly simple... can you show more code?  maybe explain your problem visually because your software vocabulary is definitely lacking.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your comments, and sorry for my poor vocabulary!

I have added a screen shot of the page I am trying to create which I hope makes what I am trying to do clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Roy

I think for starters that you are not populating all fo the required fields for the object. If you look [here](http://www.barnettech.com/content/creating-event-salesforce-php-api) you will see that the required fields are Subject, OwnerId, Start DateTime and End DateTime. If you populate all of these then it make start to work (I don't think you object is even being created currently.)

I know the example I give in the link but the theory is still the same.

Does that fix it?

Paul

Comment: Hi
I have tried population all the fields and it makes no difference, all the other fields display with the correct values apart from the Owner ID

Comment: I can't see any reason why your code wouldn't work then. Are you sure that the User is a correct user? Thats the only thing I can think of. Have you posted on the developer force boards?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a simple test case outside of your application?

I recommend hard-coding everything so you have no question about what values go where (e.g. what is _selectedEntity ?)

Comment: In this case Selected Entity is the Event object